# How should I configure Flow type checking for functions that are passed as props in a React / Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, redux, flowtype

I'm passing my Redux action creators as props throughout my app. So far, I've just been using the generic `Function` type, but I would rather have proper type checking so that I know I'm calling my action creators with the correct arguments and types.

I've tried using the existential operator (*) in my Props type, but it looks like Flow is unable to infer the function signature (it just returns `any`.)

The best solution I've come up with is to import the action creator from my reducer in all of my components, and use `typeof` to set the function type. For example:

```
import { actionCreator } from 'redux/modules/reducer'

type ComponentProps = {
    actionCreator: typeof actionCreator,
}
```

I'm happy to do this once in my main container, but this gets very repetitive if I have to recursively add all of these type definitions in all of my child components.

I'm wondering why the following isn't working in my child components:

```
type ComponentProps = {
    actionCreator: *,
}
```

I would like the function type to automatically flow down through my props, but it seems like there is a boundary between React components.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
type Action = (dispatch: Dispatch, ownProps?: { [prop: string]: any}) => void;
type ActionCreator = (param1: string, param2: number, ...) => Action;
```

**NOTE** that Using this *Dispatch* type need to include redux flow type cheat sheet.